# Pasar código creado en JavaScript a PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy intentando pasar este trozo de código de JavaScript a PHP pero no consigo implementarlo.

```
    var balas=["fallo","fallo","fallo","fallo","fallo","acierto"];
    var tiro= balas[(Math.floor(Math.random()*(balas.length)))];
    var res=balas.indexOf(tiro);
    balas.splice(res,1);
    if(balas.length==0){balas=["fallo","fallo","fallo","fallo","fallo","acierto"]}
    document.write(tiro);
```

Código de php.

```
    $balas= array("fallo","fallo","fallo","fallo","fallo","acierto");
    $tiro= array_rand($balas);    
    $balas.str_split($res,1);
    if(strlen($balas[])==0){$balas= 
    array("fallo","fallo","fallo","fallo","fallo","acierto");}
    echo $tiro;
```

Comment: Hola, por favor haz el [tour] y lee [ask] y [example]. Cuál es el problema que tienes? Qué error te está arrojando?

Comment: una respuesta digna de la pregunta: $balas= array("fallo","fallo","fallo","fallo","fallo","acierto");
$tiro = $balas[array_rand($balas)];
$res = array_search($tiro, $balas);
array_splice($balas, $res, 1);
if(count($balas)==0){$balas = array("fallo","fallo","fallo","fallo","fallo","acierto");}
echo $tiro;

Comment: Hola Andrés me da un error de código cuando llamo a balas[]

Comment: Pruebo John, Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Varias cosas están mal:

- `var res=balas.indexOf(tiro);` Si quieres mostrar el valor que hay en el índice obtenido en `tiro` tienes que usar la notación `$balas[$tiro]`, no `$balas.str_split($res,1)` De todos modos, no necesitas el valor que obtendrías en `res` para hacer el splice en PHP, pues lo harías con el valor de `tiro`
- El equivalente `splice` (JS) es `array_splice()`, no `str_split`
- Para saber la cantidad de elementos en un array, debes usar `count()`

En PHP podrías escribir entonces:

```
$balas= array("fallo","fallo","fallo","fallo","fallo","acierto");
$tiro= array_rand($balas); 
echo $balas[$tiro].PHP_EOL;
array_splice($balas,$tiro);
if(count($balas)==0) {
    $balas = array("fallo","fallo","fallo","fallo","fallo","acierto");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Cedano, que significa PHP_EOL?

Comment: @Martin es una constante predifinida que significa salto de línea, según la plataforma en que esté corriendo PHP. [Ver doc aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.constants.php). Mi código está mal, debería funcionar lo que sugiere @Jhon, la única duda sería si debe ser `array_splice($balas, $res, 1);` o `array_splice($balas, $res);` Convendría que Jhon escriba una respuesta.